# Split text and number, then convert and add numbers

Tags: excel

I have a series of values such as:

```
10RP
2.5R
5R
7.5R
10R
2.5YR
5YR
```

I want to convert the string portion to a number based on this table:

```
0   R
10  YR
20  Y
30  GY
40  G
50  BG
60  B
70  PB
80  P
90  RP
```

I then want to create two columns so that:

```
2.5YR
```

becomes:

```
2.5 10
```

In a third column I will add the two numbers together.

Can this be done just using formulas? I want to avoid using VBA if I can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach.

`seq` is a defined name referring to an array constant `={1,2,3,4,5}`

If you might have numbers that encompass more than five characters, just extend the constant appropriately.

```
Number part:  =LOOKUP(9E+307,--MID(A1,1,seq))

Letter portion converted to number: 

    =VLOOKUP(MID(A1,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,1,seq)),seq)+1,9),$F$1:$G$10,2,FALSE)
```

Where your table is in `F1:G10` and reversed so that the letters are in the first column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient but should work

```
=IFERROR((LEFT(F3,LEN(F3)-2)+VLOOKUP(RIGHT(F3,2),$A$3:$B$12,2,0)), 
         (LEFT(F3,LEN(F3)-1)+VLOOKUP(RIGHT(F3,1),$A$3:$B$12,2,0)))
```

Where your lookup table is A3:B12 with the letters in the left-most column
Check for the two-letter combinations before the single-letter ones.